# Downloadable W3C docs (for offline)?

Tags: html, css

Somebody know where I can download archive with W3C web site within latest updates for CSS3 and HTML5 specifications?
If no.. Where i can download good docs about new CSS3 properties?

Big thanks and sorry for bad english ;)

```
+ to answers: https://github.com/w3c
```

Comment: Something like [this](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html)?

Comment: Thanks for ALL. You are helped me a lot. If I choose a specific
answer as "best", it would not be fair to others. Let
everyone know what his response is good
for me and the time that you spent on the
response is not lost in vain.
I love you guys. Haha

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at: http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/specs.en.html

You can see the status of each Module and read whichever ones are most relevant today. Additionally you can print an individual module or you can print the entire CSS 2.1 by downloading it, you have a few options, e.g.

`This document is also available in these non-normative formats: plain text, gzip'ed tar file, zip file, gzip'ed PostScript, PDF. See also translations.`

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/

Its in your best interest to stick to learning from http://w3.org only - try to avoid other sources when possible (thats just my preference, YPMV)

Also check out http://www.w3.org/standards/techs/css#w3c_all for an easier way to visualize which specs are past the [Candidate Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/2005/10/Process-20051014/tr) stage.

Comment: +1 for sticking to w3.org only. http://w3fools.com/